# Display data from a serial port in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am getting some parameters through serial port (name and values) and want to show in jTable.
how to do that ?

Comment: Are these values changing? Can you already read them? Do you have them available in Java already?

Comment: yes these value will be changing on real time also i want a button that i can save these when ever i need.

Comment: The question really should be what table model is needed in order to use jTable when reading/streaming serial data using RXTX library. For instance the current version of Arduino puts all data in a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

start by reading http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

if you have done and have more specific questions feel free to come back and ask them but you really need to do some selfstudy yourself